# Is it possible to VPN over SSH (or in some other way change up my network subnet), and how?

Tags: networking, vpn

For reasons I have yet to ascertain (but I suspect they are legacy, and practically impossible at this point to change), the VPN in use at work uses the subnet `192.168.1.X`.

The astute among you will recognize this as the home network subnet that practically every device comes preconfigured to use.

At home, this was an easy fix - I just changed my router to use `192.168.42.x`. But when I'm visiting other people... yeah, can connect to the VPN but can't do anything because networks.

So I'm wondering if it's possible (and if so, **how**) to do something that would let me make my computer believe that it's on `192.168.42.x` when it connects to the VPN, so that traffic does something like this:

my computer (Mac OSX) ---(192.168.1.x traffic) ---> VPN
                          \
                           +--(192.168.x.x traffic) ---> (either my home network, or whatever network I'm currently connected to. Don't really care.)

Is that possible, and if so, how?

Comment: Connect to a VPN then while connect to the VPN. connect to the work VPN

Comment: @Ramhound, nope. Does. not. Work. (and I just spent 5 hours making sure that it doesn't)